# how to validated to enter numbers only and show alert message when special charter entered

Tags: laravel

I want to validate input filed which allow entering numbers only and if numeric, alphabet or copy paste not allowed and show the alert message.

```
 <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" placeholder="Amount" class="form-control"></div>
```

This my input field.
I search on google but not getting a proper answer.

Comment: Have you checked official documentation?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules

Comment: Thanks for the reply @matiit. But I want to validate input field in blade file at the time of entering input field I want to show the alert message.

Comment: If it have selective inputs in the text field reactively, it might be better on the front-end validation. Probably, you can use JQuery, Vue.js or even simple JavaScript. This is just my opinion though, not necessarily the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

From the client side you might want to create an input that already validates, to prevent unnecissary requests

```
<input type="text" name="amount" pattern="[0-9]*" title="Numbers only">
```

or

```
<input type="number" name="amount" title="Numbers only">
```

Next you want to validate the same on the server, to protect your request.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'amount' => 'required|nummeric',
    ]);

    // do something with amount
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a server side validation as below

In your **model**

```
public static function rules()
    {
        return [
            'amount' => ['required','numeric'],
        ];
    }
```

In your **controller** write below code

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Your ModelName::rules()); 
        if ($validator->fails()){
           //display error msg
        }
```